# Missing objects when opening a pdf in illustrator

Tags: pdf, import, adobe-illustrator, illustrator-cs6

I am creating my own pdf with itextpdf (java) and it opens up correctly in any PDF reader and it seems to be ok if I place the pdf into a illustrator project. However, if I embed or directly open the pdf in Illustrator CS6, many objects are missing.
They are not just hidden - they are gone.

How can I fix this issue with illustrator?

[image: ISSUE demo]]

Comment: Are the missing objects raster images or vector? Did you try viewing the file in artwork mode?